# how to get expiration date for users in a CSV file using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, csv

```
Import-CSV -Path .\csv_file.csv | ForEach-Object { 
    Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False} –Properties “DisplayName”, “msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed” |
    Select-Object -Property “Displayname”,@{Name=“ExpiryDate”;Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.“msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed”)}}
} | Export-Csv .\results.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This works great but gets all USERS in AD. We have thousands of Users.

I want to get users that are in a CSV file (1st column). If possible, I'd love to create a second column in the same file with the expiration date.

The CSV file

```
Jason.Bourne
Thomas.Smith
Judy.Doe
Topsy.kret
```

I modified my PowerShell Script but not sure how to get the value from the CSV file into Get-ADUser

Comment: What format is your csv file in? Can you provide an example to show this... make up names etc if needed to protect privacy.

Comment: @JamesC. I updated my code and added the CSV file format. It's a very simple CSV file since it only contains the samaccountname

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a `samaccountname` header in the csv file eg:

```
samaccountname
Jason.Bourne
Thomas.Smith
Judy.Doe
Topsy.kret
```

You can use `-Identity $_.samaccountname` to get each user in turn:

```
Import-CSV -Path C:\folder\input.csv | ForEach-Object { 
    Get-ADUser -Identity $_.samaccountname –Properties DisplayName,msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed,Enabled,PasswordNeverExpires | Select-Object -Property Displayname,Enabled,PasswordNeverExpires,@{Name="ExpiryDate";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}}
} | Export-CSV C:\folder\results.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I am getting errors. Get-ADUser : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '@{Jason.Bourne=Thomas.Smith}'.

Comment: I added a header row with Username and same thing. Get-ADUser : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '@{samaccountname=Jason.Bourne}'

Comment: I've updated my answer with two ways to correct this

Comment: I just tried all three and same issue. A positional parameter cannot be found.

Comment: You've added the header to the csv file? If so that changes everything again.

Comment: I had no header. I added one. then i removed it.
It's easy to modify the csv file. However each time I run it, i get the same error.

Comment: `@{Jason.Bourne=Thomas.Smith}'` and `@{samaccountname=Jason.Bourne}` are different errors as it depends how you reference the data. I've updated my answer with a single solution that uses the header that you added.

Comment: Thanks for the help. One last thing, if I wanted to add pwdLastSet as another column, would I just add @{Name="Password Last Set";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."pwdLastSet")}} to the end?